# Gnome grouping of windows for minimization and focus

Tags: gnome, xorg, 19.10, window-manager

I run Ubuntu 19.10 with Gnome. I recently switched to a 4K monitor. With the extra real estate, I've been putting windows into corners and on left and right halves. Invariably, Gnome decides that some windows go together, such that when I minimize one it minimizes others, or that when I focus one it brings to front some window on the other side of the screen. I don't want this behavior. I don't want any windows tied to other windows. How do I turn it off? (And what's the technical term for it as I can't find it by searching the web.)

Comment: How do you minimize? Maybe you clicked to show desktop? Maybe tiling windows manager is installed? Like i3 or some other that makes this mistake?

Comment: Install gnome-tweaks and go in Windows and try to disable Attach Modal Dialogs.

Comment: @JerareYoshi, "Attach Modal Dialogs" is already disabled for me.

Comment: @Kangarooo, to minimize I click the little '-' near the 'x' on the window. "Edge Tiling" in Tweaks is disabled also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ends up that this is actually a shelltile extension "feature". See https://github.com/emasab/shelltile

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides attach-modal-dialogs false
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs false
```

Comment: Those values are already false for me.